# JQuery return "Undefined" value in ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, asp.net-core

I'm trying to create a dynamic menu, when I run the `Web API`, I can get correct JSON string, but when I run `Razor Pages`, I only get the `"Undefined"`. Anythings wrong in my `JQuery`?

Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    getData();
    getTopMenu();
    SideMenu();
});

function SideMenu() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "https://localhost:44328/api/menus",
        success: function (data) {
            buildMenu($('#menu'), data);
            $('#menu').menu();
        }
    });

    function buildMenu(parent, items) {
        $.each(items, function () {
            var li = $("<li>" + this.MenuName + "</li>");
            if (this.ActiveNo == 0) {
                li.addClass('ui-state-disabled');
            }

            li.appendTo(parent);

            if (this.MenuList && this.MenuList.length > 0) {
                var ul = $("<ul></ul>");
                ul.appentTo(li);
                buildMenu(ul, this.MenuList);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that your code doesn't work when the WebAPI project isn't running? If so that's expected behaviour.

Comment: Or CORS related? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS Since I see you using the localhost:portnr instead of a relative path.

Comment: I'm using CORS and my WebAPI is working, but when i run it, only get Undefined value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.MenuName` <- this is the problem, cause it didn't follow the JSON string, it should be `this.menuName`